# Adobe Reader keeps freezing when multiple windows are open

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I need to have multiple PDF's open at once, and after about 10 minutes Adobe Acrobat Reader freezes. I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit and have the latest version of reader. The computer had been running slower than normal and I did a virus scan and it found 'Diplugem' and 'Hadsruda' which it deleted, but maybe they did something to screw it up.

Comment: Which Acrobat Reader version are you using?

Comment: @MaxWyss 15 and I signed in to sync